# Racket: Change two constants with one function

Tags: scheme, constants, racket

I wanna change two constants at the same time with one function, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
(define p 1)
(define q 1)

(define (change p q)
  (set! p (+ p 1))
  (set! q (+ q 1)))
```

Comment: This function does work, it just doesn't work how you think it should. What happens is that you have two p's bound and two q's bound. This function changes the value of the p and q that are it's formal parameters, but does not change p and q in the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probable that you're using a language that doesn't have implicit `begin` inside procedure bodies, so let's try writing it explicitly:

```
(define p 1) ; declare variables as global, so they 
(define q 1) ; can be modified inside a procedure

(define (change-vars) ; don't pass them, they won't get modified inside proc
  (begin ; use begin to evaluate expressions sequentially from left to right
    (set! p (+ p 1))
    (set! q (+ q 1)))) ; value of last expression is returned, here's #<void>
```

It works as expected:

```
p
=> 1
q
=> 1

(change-vars)

p
=> 2
q
=> 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Óscar! I didn't knew about "begin" that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
#lang racket
(define p 1)
(define q 1)

(define (increment-p-and-q)
  (set! p (+ p 1))
  (set! q (+ q 1)))


(display (list p q)) ; displays (1 1)
(newline)
(increment-p-and-q)  ; mutates p and q
(display (list p q)) ; displays (2 2)
(newline)
```

When you call a procedure that has the same binding as a global variable it gets shadowed. If you `set!` it's the local binding that gets changed, not the global one.

Comment: @JimBoy I've updated the code with a full example. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: I keep getting the following error message: define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part

Comment: @JimBoy My code does work with `Determine language from source` in the bottom left and `#lang racket` as the first line, but you're not using that are you? If you're using a different language (and there are dozens supported by DrRacket) you need to include that in your question and we'll update our answer.

Comment: Thank you, Sylwester. See above.

Answer (score 1):

@Sylwester gave a good, literal answer to your question. Another literal answer would be, if you want a function to mutate its arguments (treating them like reference arguments in C++), use [boxes](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/boxes.html). Example:

```
(define (change p)
  (set-box! p (+ (unbox p) 1)))

(define p (box 1))

(for/list ([i 3])
  (change p)
  (unbox p))
; => '(2 3 4)
```

**However**, using mutation like this is not common or encouraged in Racket. Although you *can* do it, a more functional approach is encouraged and can even [allow Racket to optimize your code to run faster](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/performance.html#%28part._.Mutation_and_.Performance%29).

Comment: The problem with both solutions is that they work fine if one want's to only change one constant, but the program breaks if one tries to change two constants.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro (define-syntax-rule in this case), this way you **can** pass the variables as parameters:

```
#lang racket

(define p 1)
(define q 1)

(define-syntax-rule (change p q)
  (begin
    (set! p (+ p 1))
    (set! q (+ q 1))))

(display (list p q)) ; displays (1 1)
(newline)
(change p q)  ; mutates p and q
(display (list p q)) ; displays (2 2)
(newline)
```